# how to disable desktop right-click options like(Refresh, Properties and etc) using c#

Tags: c#, visual-c++

How to disable desktop `right-click` options like(`Refresh, Properties` and etc) using `c#`?

Please give me the codings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Please give me the codings_ is not a good way to ask. Did you tried _anything_? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help]

Answer (score 0):

Via the Registry

There’s a registry entry you can add to disable the mouse right click. This only works on the desktop and Explorer though and doesn’t affect any programs, you can also still right click on the task bar and control the tray programs via right click. This obviously isn’t the best solution around but it does provide a small level of desktop protection over accidentally doing something via the Explorer context menu.

1. Go to Start -> Run or press Win key+R and type Regedit, then hit Enter. Navigate to the following key in the registry:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
2. Right click on the Explorer key and select New -> DWORD Value.

1. Give it the name NoViewContextMenu and click OK. Then double click the name and set the value data as 1. Press OK. To set it back again simply set this value back to 0 or right click on the NoViewContextMenu entry and delete it. You will need to log off or reboot for any of these changes to take effect.

Adding the registry tweak above will disable the mouse right click for all users on the computer. If you only want to disable for the currently logged in user, you should navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
For ease of use and to save you going into the registry we have created these keys in easy to run .reg files which simply need to be double clicked on.

Read more: http://www.raymond.cc/blog/restrict-or-disable-mouse-right-click-at-desktop-and-explorer/#ixzz2uiGVoU4M

How to Read and write registry: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C